# How to pass argument (which is a command instead of file name) to new shell using execve?

Tags: c, linux, execv

I am trying to send arguments(e.g:ls,date,cal) to a new shell ,execute those arguments and terminate.

```
  #include"header.h"  //includes all the header files

 int main(int argc,char * argv[],char *envp[]) {
     char *ap[]={"sh","ls",NULL};
     int p=execve("/bin/sh",ap,envp);
     printf("error:%d",p);

     perror("execve");

 }
```

output:

```
sh:0:can't open ls
```

Comment: Header.c is a user defined one which includes all the necessary library files

Comment: what about `char *ap[]={"ls",NULL};`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do, but I think that should be `{"sh", "-c", "ls", 0}`.  `-c` means "the next argument is a command"; without it, the first non-option argument to `sh` is interpreted as the name of a shell script to invoke.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with `execve`. Your program correctly invokes `sh ls`.

It's just that `sh` interprets its first argument as the name of a shell script to run, but there is no file called `ls` in the current directory, hence the error. You'd get the same results by running `sh ls` manually.

If all you want to do is run `ls`, why go through the shell at all? Just do:

```
char *ap[]={"ls",NULL};
int p=execve("/usr/bin/ls",ap,envp);
```

On the other hand, if you want to use the shell, you need to tell it that its argument is supposed to be a command, not the name of a file. You do that with `sh -c ls`:

```
char *ap[]={"sh","-c","ls",NULL};
```

Comment: Or `execlp("ls", "ls", (char *)0)` to get path searching.  (Note: that `char *` cast is necessary, _even if_ you prefer to write null pointers as NULL.)

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: @zwol Ah yes, cast needed because of the `...` of  `int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);`

Comment: @zwol I always do `(char *)NULL`, but I think the cast is technically not required on platforms that define `NULL` as `((void *)0)`.

Comment: @melpomene No, it's required even if that is the definition of NULL, because `void *` and `char *` are not required to be passed the same way through a variable argument list.  (I have a vague memory that C11 changed that but I don't remember for sure, and anyway it's about 15 years too soon to be assuming C11.)

Comment: @zwol Ah, great fun.